# Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'

Tags: angular, validation, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I have angular reactive form in parent component and sections inside childrens component.

Inside the child component I have a checkbox - when its checked - more fields open and I want them all to be required.

I am using setValidators but I'm getting error

> ParentFormComponent.html:3 ERROR Error:
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value:
>   'ng-valid: false'.
>       at viewDebugError (core.js:7601)
>       at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:7589)
>       at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:7691)
>       at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:10560)
>       at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:10541)
>       at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:11144)
>       at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (core.js:11098)
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ParentFormComponent.html:3)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11087)
>       at checkNoChangesView (core.js:10442)
>
> ParentFormComponent.html:3 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object,
>   nodeIndex: 2, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}

this is the line of ParentFormComponent.html:3

```
 <form [formGroup]="parentForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
```

Here is my code:

```
<label class="container">DB
    <input #db type="checkbox" name="db" (change)="checkValue(db.name, db.checked)"> 
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

<div *ngIf="db.checked" formGroupName="_monitorDB">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Server name" formControlName="ServerName">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="DataBase name" formControlName="DbName">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="table name" formControlName="DB_tableName">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="port" formControlName="DbPort">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Query" formControlName="Query">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Permissions" formControlName="Premissions">
    </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

and in the ts file:

```
checkValue(name:string, event: any){
    if (event == true){
      this.test.push(name);
      if (name =="db"){
         this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('ServerName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DbName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DB_tableName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DbPort').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('Query').setValidators([Validators.required]);
         this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('Premissions').setValidators([Validators.required]);

      }

    }

    else{
      const index: number = this.test.indexOf(name);
      if (index !== -1) {
          this.test.splice(index, 1);
          if (name =="db"){
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('ServerName').clearValidators();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('ServerName').updateValueAndValidity();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DbName').clearValidators();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DbName').updateValueAndValidity();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DB_tableName').clearValidators();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DB_tableName').updateValueAndValidity();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DbPort').clearValidators();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('DbPort').updateValueAndValidity();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('Query').clearValidators();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('Query').updateValueAndValidity();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('Premissions').clearValidators();
            this.childForm.get('_monitorDB').get('Premissions').updateValueAndValidity();
          }
      }      
    }

     this.checkboxArr.emit(this.test);
 }
```

Comment: can you provide minimal reproducible code on stackblitz.

Answer (score 60):

I faced the same issue and I fixed it by using `AfterViewChecked` and `ChangeDetectorRef`:

```
import { AfterViewChecked, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

export class ClassName implements AfterViewChecked {
  constructor(private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

Comment: works, thanks! would have been nice to have an explanation what this fix does.
*ngAfterVIewChecked* is called every time Angular has finished running change detection on a component and it's children.
Great intro: https://indepth.dev/posts/1058/a-gentle-introduction-into-change-detection-in-angular

Comment: Fantastic solution. Worked for me like a charm. Thanks

Comment: This is the correct solution

Comment: Even if this solves the problem, calling `detectChanges()` every time `ngAfterViewChecked()` lifecycle hook is called, isn't optimal. Just see how many times `ngAfterViewChecked()` is called (with a `console.log`). A better solution is calling `detectChanges()` just in the moment you need it (for the concrete problem in the main post: after the validators are set).

Comment: As @JoséAntonioPostigo mentioned above, `ngAfterViewChecked()` is not necessary. In my case, calling `detectChanges()` alone right after adding a control worked fine.

Comment: this worked for me.. tks <3

Comment: This seems like just silencing the actual problem

Answer (score 11):

Change the ChangeDetectionStrategy on the parent component to : `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. Simple and clean.

**Edit** This actually not a solution, it will just hide the error. Please take a look at the github link posted in the comments.

Comment: Can you elabore more on that? Why change the detection strategy?

Comment: Please see more discussion here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23657#issuecomment-653939615

Comment: According to the github thread you share, this "solution" actual don't resolve the error but just hide it and can break a lot of thing. So before using it, make sure what the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush imply for you

Comment: At the time, it let me get past that error, so I posted the solution. But I have edited my solution. You will have to debug this error.

Answer (score 7):

I am facing same issue I know it's not a way but the only solution I've found is setTimeout

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
 setTimeout(() => {
    this.form.patchValue({
    name: 'xyz',
    email: 'abc@gmail.com',
    phone: '0987654321'
   })
  }, );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if it's the right thing to do but i solved it by changing:

```
<div *ngIf="db.checked" formGroupName="_monitorDB">
```

to

```
<div [hidden]="!db.checked" formGroupName="_monitorDB">
```

Comment: this is not the right practice, because your elements are available in the form, which creates a performance issue if you have large form. If my provided answer isn't helpful for you, then please let me know, I will give you an answer without rxweb approach.

Comment: This worked for me where I tried to show or hide a part of the form when I use a checkbox to do this procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` should do a trick

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-center-location-step3',
  templateUrl: './test-center-location-step3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-center-location-step3.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Track where the field is changed and mark the component for changeDetection... it could be in a function or one of Angular lifecycle hooks like AfterViewChecked

```
constructor(
    private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
) {
}

// mark for check where change is happening
this._cdr.markForCheck();
this._cdr.detectChanges();
```

Changing changeDetection to ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush will also solve the problem but it might cause other problems, you will need to manually mark the component for check.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to never use `setTimeout` as I think it's a bad practice, but I have lately found that when creating custom components and interacting with the DOM, this is sometimes necessary.

However, when I've used it, it has been with a delay of `0ms`. Just wrapping the action in a `setTimeout` with **no delay** will be enough to move the action to the end of the execution queue, which will solve numerous issues with the interaction between Angular and the DOM.

### TL,DR

```js
setTimeout(() => actionThatCausesTheError(), 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me, i have this custom form that list a bunch of questions from backend dynamically, then i need to patch the value after retrieval of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
ngOnInit():void
{
   this._monitorDB.patchValue({
    ServerName: 'ServerName',
    DbName: 'DbName',
    DB_tableName: 'DB_tableName',
    DbPort: 'DbPort',
    Query: 'Query',
    Premissions:'Premissions'
   });
}
```