# Disable angular form after init

Tags: angular

I have template-driven form in Angular, like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="item">

  <form #inputForm="ngForm
        (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()"
        ...>

    <input [(ngModel)]="item.code" ...
    <input ...
    <ng-select .. 
    <mat-checkbox ..

  </form>

</ng-container>
```

How can I disable all controls inside form after the component is loaded?

Thanks. T.

Comment: Maybe you could just do `[disabled]="false"` on each form input in the template. [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zxkyp9?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fmain.html)

Comment: Yes, its an option. But I have a lot of controls on the form, so I tried to find out some solution, how to do it all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this. Let my know if I'm on the right track.

```
@ViewChild('inputForm') inputForm!: NgForm;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.disableControls();
}

private disableControls(): void {
  Object.keys(this.inputForm.controls).forEach(controlName => {
    const control = this.inputForm.controls[controlName];
    control.disable();
   );
}
```

Comment: this.inputForm?.controls is empty in ngAfterViewInit.
But, when I call disableControls later (i added button which calls this function), it works correctly. But i need to disable controls when form is shown/loaded. 

see stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wzsspp

Comment: Try with `ngAfterViewChecked`, it works for me on stackblitz you provided. Also, take a look at this question and all of it's answers, it may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53901392/expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-previous-value-ng-valid-true-c

Comment: Strange, there is an error in my case: Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'ng-valid': 'true'. Current value: 'false'. Expression location: App component. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: Yeah, that's why I provided following link.

Answer (score 1):

Ah. Yes, there is a problem with this `template-driven` form. Anyway, you do a little bit of workaround here in order to fix this.

```
@ViewChild('inputForm') inputForm!: NgForm;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  setTimeout(()=> this.inputForm.form.disable())
}
```

Comment: It seems to work, but timeout must be bigger .. for example 100ms. Without this, ng-select is not disabled correctly.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's ok. It's workaround. I will share the best solution later on, for sure.